# Simultaneous equations to solve unknown exponents

Tags: systems-of-equations

Solved the following simultaneous equations for $a$ and $b$:

(1)

$$a + 2b = 2\\3a + b = 10$$

$$3a + 6b = 6\\3a + b = 10$$

$$5b = -4$$

$$b = \frac{-4}{5}\\a = \frac{18}{5}$$

(2)

How do we use the answers/information in (1) to solve the following equations for $x$ and $y$?

$$2^{x+2y} = 2^{20}\\5^{5x+y} = 25^{x+50}$$

In general how do these types of equations relate?

Comment: Hint:
$$
a^x = a^y \quad \text{if and only if} \quad x = y
$$
Also, you have to make a sanity check. For example for expressions like
$$
2^x = 3^y
$$ there are no integer solutions because the left-hand-side is always even and the right-hand-side is always odd.

Comment: A thousand apologies i mistyped the second equation in question (2) your Hint focused my mind.

Comment: The second equation can be turned to $5^{3x+y}=5^{100}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $25^{x+50}=(5^2)^{x+50}=5^{2x+100}$ so the system can be written as

$$2^{x+2y} = 2^{20}\\5^{5x+y} = 5^{2x+100}$$

or

$$2^{x+2y} = 2^{20}\\5^{3x+y} = 5^{100}$$

and comparing exponents we obtain

$$x+2y=20$$
$$3x+y=100$$

This is very similar to the system

$$a + 2b = 2\\3a + b = 10$$

but the RHS is multiplied by $10$. So multiplying by $10$ we have

$$10a + 2(10b) =x+2y= 20\\3(10a) + 10b =3x+y= 100$$

where $x=10a$ and $y=10b$ and you have already found $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

No worries, here is the answer for your corrected question.
$$2^{x+2y} = 2^{20} \; \; (i)$$
$$5^{5x+y} = 25^{x+50} \; \; (ii)$$

As the bases are the same, from the first equation we can derive that $x+2y=20$, so $x=20-2y$. Now we can sub this into equation $ii$

$$5^{5(20-2y)+y} = 25^{(20-2y)+50}$$
$$5^{100-9y} = 25^{70-2y}$$

We also need to recognize that $25 = 5^2$, and that $(a^m)^n=a^{mn}$, so:

$$5^{100-9y} = 5^{140-4y}$$

As both sides have the same base we only need to consider the exponents:
$$100-9y=140-4y$$

I'll let you take it from here...

Comment: You are not exploiting the resolution of the first system. Better rewrite as $$\begin{cases}x+2y=20,\\3x+y=100.\end{cases}$$

Comment: @IAmAGuest they both spit out the same answer champion...

Comment: Of course. But the fact is that you don't answer the question as asked. (Which the OP also missed.) Äres' answer is better.